# Is an eventhandler removed if the control it is set on removed?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, handler

We are developing an application that looks like this:

> Mainwindow - PaneGroup - Pane

What we want to do is add a handler (AddHandler Pane, AddressOf MethodName) on the mainwindow and throw the event in the Pane. When we want something to change on a collection in the mainwindow, we throw that event in the Pane.

My question is if the pane is removed from the panegroup (doesn't exist anymore), does that handler still live on the mainwindow?

Comment: "throw the event in the Pane" - what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: RaiseEvent onClicked(item)

Comment: And MethodName is a method on the Pane, I guess?

Comment: So the MainWindow listens to an event of the Pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pane holds a reference to the main window. When the pane is removed from the pane group it will eventually be garbage collected and in that process, the assigned event handlers will be cleared, too.

So, as long as the main window lives longer than the pane you have no problem.